# find a node value in xml using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, xmlnode

Excuse the simple question: I'm fairly new to JQuery!

I have a variable named xmlText containing an XML string chunk where I'm sure that there is only one node of type "node1", and so on.

```
<root><node1>value1</node1><node2>value2</node2></root>
```

Using JQuery I can access the value of a given node like this:

```
$('root node1', xmlText).each(function () {
 alert($(this).text();
```

});

How can I access the value witout a ".each(function()" construct?

Notice the xmltext variable is just a text chunk, xml like formated, not a complete well formated xml file nor a parsed DOM object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each` is used to loop over a collection but you can simply apply the function if you only have one element.

Simply do

```
$('root node1', xmlText).text()
```

Comment: @distroy Thanks, this is the most straightforward, simplest syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(xmlText).find('root node1').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var xmlText = $('<root><node1>value1</node1><node2>value2</node2></root>');
alert(xmlText.find('node1').text());
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/24whF/1/)